# Response.Write() in Umbraco user control clears all page content

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, umbraco

I'm using the following code to add a table to a user control in Umbraco.

```
Try
    Dim DS As DataSet = GetData()
    If DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Response.Write("<form><table>")
        For Each row In DS.Tables(0).Rows
            Response.Write("<tr>")
            Response.Write("<td> <a onclick=alert('" & row("ID") & "')>" & row("Date") & "</a></td>")
            Response.Write("<td>" & " - " & "</td>")
            Response.Write("<td>" & row("Amount") & "</td>")
            Response.Write("</tr>")
        Next
        Response.Write("</table></form>")
        Response.End()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Response.End()
End Try
```

But what happens after the loop completes (without errors - I've stepped through the whole thing), the only content left on the page is the table.

I'm sure there's something really silly I left out. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.Write()` isn't to blame in this instance, it's your `Response.End()` calls. It's not clearing the remaining page content, but actually preventing it from being run.

> **HttpResponse.End Method** 
>   Sends all currently buffered output to the client, stops execution of the page, and raises the EndRequest event. 
>   
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx

Remove them (or at least the one in the try block, if the one in the catch statement is intended) and that should fix it for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I initially didn't have the Response.End(), and this caused the web page to completely refresh after the loop finished. So it would (briefly) show the code-generated html (table) on a blank page, then switch back to the original page.

Comment: I've since abandoned this approach, and I'm using an ASP data-bound repeater instead, which is doing the job.